# Python reload textfile into string every x seconds in a loop

Tags: python, string

I am trying to read a text file into a string, do something with the string, then ever X seconds, 
re-read the text file (in case it has changed) to update the string and do the same thing again, over and over in a loop, without spawning an infinite number of processes.

so something like :

in an infinite loop
 open 'MyTextFile' and read it into a String
 do stuff with the string of text it reads from the file
 close the file (if I need to...to allow another script to write to it)
wait x seconds before clearing the string and re-reading the 
same 'MyTextFile' file to update the string and do it all again
(in an infinite loop until I tell it to stop)

What would be a good sturdy (reliable to run for a long time) way to do that?

Thanks!

```
<code>
import os
import time

myDataFile = "MyData.txt"
data = ""

def ReadFile(data):
    # only need to read it if data has changed
    # detect 'modified' date of myDataFile and only PrintToPrinter IF it has change
    # and if it has NOT changed, wait 10 seconds and check again
    # IF CHANGED
            with open (myDataFile, "r") as myFile:
                    try:
                            data=myFile.read().replace('\n', '  ')
                    finally:
                            myFile.close()
                ShowOnScreen(data)
                PrintToPrinter(data)
    # ELSE 
        # data has not changed..
        # no need to print it so I shouldn't send back to PrintToPrinter
        # but I still want to ShowOnScreen(data) on screen
        # and keep the program running to check for changes
        ShowOnScreen(data)
        sleep(10)
        ReadFile(data)

def ShowOnScreen(data):
        print(time+' '+data)

def PrintToPrinter(data):
    # send DateTimeStamp+data to printer here
    # go back to checking for changes
    ReadFile(data)

# kick off the program to start looking for changes
# data starts out as "" so it should always read the first time
# and send to printer and screen
ReadFile(data)
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time from sleep
import datetime
import time
# probably should not import both time and datetime

MyFile = "MyFile.txt"
MyText = ""
MyDate = ""

def GetDateTime():
    MyDate = time.strftime("%x %I:%M %p")
    return MyDate+" "

def ReadFile(MyText):
    with open (MyFile, "r" as myfile:
        try:
            MyText2=myfile.read().replace('\n','  ')
        finally:
            myfile.close()

            CurDateTime = GetDateTime()

            if (MyText == MyText2):
                # file hasn't changed...print to screen only
                print CurDateTime
                sleep(5)
                ReadFile(MyText2)
            else:
                # print to screen and printer
                print CurDateTime +MyText2
                # send CurDateTime +MyText2 to printer
                sleep(5)
                ReadFile(MyText2)

ReadFile(MyText)
```

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using the `time.sleep` from the `time` module. A sample code is pasted below:

```
import time

def file_handler(filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        line = fh.read()
        print line
        print "Length of string:%s"% len(line)
        fh.close()


while True:
    file_handler("test.txt")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: That is not exactly it. I think I need to explain it a little better...will edit question and try again.

Comment: Yeah its not going to be exactly what you need. I just showed a really crude way to having to repeat a function in a time loop